# Mapping two Lists/Sets

Tags: map, bulkification, set

I am trying to get my head around mapping two sets (or if this is even the right approach).

The objective is to take the name of a custom object (which is currently an email address) and map it to a User Record with a matching email address and update the owner with the user record ID. 
This update needs to be done daily after external integration is completed, and I have created a process builder trigger for the code, which works in theory (it fires, but I haven't tested it calling the actual code).

After a lot of trial and error, I've got a few steps down the road since I posted this question.  The code below works, but I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant way to do this?

```
    public static void UpdateSROwner()
    {
//getting email and ID from lists of active users 
        List<User> userList = new List<User>([SELECT Email, Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND Name != 'xyz' AND (ProfileId = 'xyz123')]);
//get list of SR records (name, SRCode and OwnerID) with conditions
        List<object__c> srList = new List<object__c>([SELECT Name, srCode__c, OwnerID, ID FROM object__c WHERE Name <> 'unmapped']);

        List<object__c> srListToUpdate = new List<object__c>();
//Looping through the filtered srList, then Looping through users to see whether the user email = SR name
        for(object__c sr: srList) 
        {
            for(User u: userList) 
            {
                if(u.Email == sr.Name)
                {
//If user email does = sr name, add record to the list and assign new ownerID
                    Object__c srToAdd = sr;
                    srToAdd.OwnerID = u.ID;
//make sure that the list doesn't already contain the record
                    if(!srListToUpdate.contains(srToAdd))
                    {
                        srListToUpdate.add(srToAdd);
                    }
                }
            }                                              
        }                                      

        update srListToUpdate;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! If you've already tried to write the code to accomplish this, sharing what you've tried so far (via an [edit]) is helpful. It shows the community that you've made an attempt to solve the problem, and helps people write relevant, accurate answers.

Comment: Right now, it's also not very clear what the end goal is. My best guess is that you're trying to update the `ownerId` field of your custom object records, based on matching the `SRCode__c` field against the `User` emails, but it'd be good to hear that in your own words. Last thing, how often are your custom records being inserted or updated? Depending on the answer to that, you might want to look at using a trigger rather than a scheduleable/batch class.

Comment: @Janet, what you explained seems a little unclear. What is it that you are exactly attempting to accomplish here? Any existing code that you have written can help us help you. Please use the edit option in the existing post to include the code that you have already written.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the input!  I hope these updates suffice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does include some inefficiencies that I think you can address.

```
    //Looping through the filtered srList, then Looping through users to see whether the user email = SR name
    for(object__c sr: srList) {
        for(User u: userList) {
            if(u.Email == sr.Name) {
```

I call this pattern a combinatoric search - I'm not sure if there's a more formal name for it. Nearly any time you are iterating over *two* lists in nested `for` loops and making comparisons between every possible pair of values - which is exactly what you're doing here - you can eliminate the inner loop using a Map for significant performance and complexity gains.

For N `Object__c` records and M `User` records, the inner loop body will execute N * M times as written here. If you have 100 Users and 100 SRs (not an outrageous data volume!) you're looking at *10,000* iterations. That will have a performance hit.

Instead, loop over one of the lists first to create a Map indexing the attribute in which you're interested:

```
Map<String, User> userMap = new Map<String, User>();

for (User u : userList) {
    // Handling duplicate values left as an exercise for the reader,
    // as it's typically dependent on the business requirements.
    userMap.put(u.Email, u); 
}
```

and then do

```
for(object__c sr: srList) {
    if (userMap.containsKey(sr.Name)) {
        // Get the User record from the Map and make updates.
    }
}
```

Here, the two loops combined will execute a maximum of N + M, rather than N * M, times. Maps allow you to add this constant-time access property to one of your loops. For even moderate values of N or M or both, this means the difference between your code getting a CPU limit exception and completing successfully with enough performance to keep users happy.

```
                //make sure that the list doesn't already contain the record
                if(!srListToUpdate.contains(srToAdd)){
                    srListToUpdate.add(srToAdd);
                }
```

This deduplication bit can be done away with if you do as above, because you have no possibility of adding the same SR twice for different Users (you've got to solve the duplicate problem in other ways).

Comment: YOU ROCK.  Thank you - I've managed to build on what you gave me and include a lookup to the child accounts using your guidance and have bulkified and updated over 1000 accounts with 4 queries.  Thank you so much.  and Derek and Jigar, thank you so much for gently helping me post a better first question :)

Comment: @JanetC Welcome to SFSE! Glad this worked out.